# Twitter Follow Button: Get the status (followed or not) of the button on load with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter, twitter-follow

**I need to get the status of a twitter "follow" button on load, not on click.**

I'm currently loading the button via ajax, and call twttr.widgets.load() to get the widjet.js to do it's magic.

I am aware of binding "follow" and "unfollow" to accept the callbacks from clicking the buttons, but how do I detect the current state of the button before any user interaction?

*For instance, the page loads and the user is signed into twitter and currently following the target of the follow button, so it appears that they've already followed the user.*

How do I detect this with javascript/jquery? I am not authorizing them through twitter at this point, so I can't check via their api.

Other attempts:

> I've also tried getting the contents of the iframe via javascript,
>   since the twitter follow button iframe has a class specifying the
>   state of the button, but it doesn't seem to be possible due to CORS.

Comment: Wow, 15 hours and not one person can answer this? That has to be a record for SO  :P

Comment: You just have to ask the right questions. Try the PayPal api. I have questions that were never answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the answer is *you can't*.

The twitter follow button is in an iframe expressly to prevent you from accessing it and obtaining information they don't want you to have.

Facebook operates similarly. The like button is in an iframe, and therefore you cannot use it to determine if a person has 'liked' a particular page. That information requires permission from the user.

Comment: In reading and exploring further on this, they want you to authenticate the user through twitter. I suppose this makes sense, but I still am having a hard time understand why detecting the status of the button would be a bad thing for a website to do.